Continuity of a differentiable function

Let $f$ be differentiable at every value of $x$, and suppose that
$f(1)=1$, $f'<0$ on $(-\infty,1)$, and  $f'>0$ on $(1,\infty)$

Show that $f(x)\geq1$ for all x.
Must $f'(1)=0$. Explain (Thomas's Calculus, Mean Value Theorem)


The function is decreasing over $(-\infty,1)$. Since $f(1)=1$,$f$ must be greater than 1 for $x<1$.
Similarly, the function is increasing  over $(1,\infty)$ and since  $f(1)=1$, $f$ must be greater than 1 for $x>1$.
The derivative of the function turns from negative to positive at $x=1$. This is only possible for a differentiable function when there is a turning point, and hence the derivative is zero.
However, I have done this without using the Mean Value Theorem (and the question is in that section, so the "textbook answer") would likely be using the MVT.
Can anyone provide an MVT based answer?

The first part requires use of MVT. Your argument about decreasing/increasing makes implicit use of MVT and I am not sure if one needs to explicitly use MVT here (check if your textbook proves the theorem regarding increasing/decreasing functions using MVT). The second part is an easy consequence of the first part. Your argument is correct here as well provided you understand the proof that derivative vanishes at a turning point.

For the first part:
Let $b$ be some number greater than $1$. Then, by the mean value theorem, $$\frac{f(b) - f(1)}{b-1} = f'(c)$$
Now, since $c$ is some number between $(1,b)$, $f'(c) > 0$ which implies $f(b) > f(1) = 1$, the rest follows.
And for the $2^\text{nd}$ one:
Let $m < 1$ and $n > 1$ be two real numbers. Without loss of generality, assume that $f(m) < f(n)$ and let $f(l)$ be such that $l > 1$ and $f(l) = f(m)$ (you can do this by IVT). Applying mean value theorem to this gives: there exists a number $c$ between $m$, $l$ such that $f'(c) = 0$; and there's just one value for which it's permitted which is $c = 1$.

I like your solution. However, could you give a solution that uses the Mean Value Theorem?

Sure, for the first one, let a = 1 and b be some number greater than 1 hence applying the mean value theorem from a to b, f(b)-f(1)/b-1 = f'(c) and since c > 1 f'(c) > 0 hence f(b) > f(1) = 1 hence I think you can do the rest ,and for the 2nd part let a and b be some number less then and greater then 1 then without loss of generality assume that f(b) > f(a) [ you can assume other case as well ] then there's an c between (1,b) such that f(c) = f(a) hence by applying mean value theorem to it there's exist and d such that f'(d) = 0 and there's only one value which permits it which is d = 1, done

Between the first and the second part, do your a and b have the same meaning, or different meanings? Also, it would be great if you moved this part to the answer. That way it is much easier to read and understand.
